# The peculiarities of using Type2/Type3 Conditionals with regard to the shifting of tenses

Tags: conditionals

When making out sentences in narration of the past time events and implementing the Conditional Mood, shall the time shift principles be observed? For example:

1. [conveying the idea of unreal condition tallying with the author's time or the future from that point of vew] "Looking at him I knew that he would do the job well if he could have the opportunity of arriving next week". Or should it be the forms of Type3 Conditional in any case because the situation unwinds in the past as to the reader's time (i.e."Looking at him I knew that he would have done the job well if he could have had the opportunity of arriving next week"?
2. [conveying the idea of unreal condition situation unwinding before the author's time] "Looking at him I knew that he would have done the job well if he could have had the opportunity of arriving a week before".

Comment: Numbered conditionals are peculiar to ESOL at individual schools and various textbooks. They aren't standard, and most English speakers know nothing about them. They're just quick recipes for if-then statements that mostly work in many situations, and are easy to teach. They don't come close to the whole story.

Comment: @John Lawler I also do not strongly abide by numbering the forms of Conditional Mood. Here I put up the classification by L.G.Alexander. What would be your authoritative oppinion on what form of Conditional should be used as applied to my pattern No.1? And does its use have anithing to do with the priority of actions depicted by the conditional clause over the author's time notwithstanding the whole situation's lying in the sphere of the past.

Comment: I.e. "I knew" stands in time before the abstract possibility of his doing the job well provided he can arrive next week ("that next week" being in the future with reference to the author's time nevertheless lies in the demesne of the past as to the reader's time).

Comment: I am bringing up this question because as it stands in books on the English Grammar we must use the Type3 Conditional always when the situation refers to the past. Cases considering the priority of actions and the author's time wich is seen as present to the whole situation in narration are not touched upon at all.

Comment: I am not familiar with the works or classifications of L. G. Alexander. In 50 years of studying English grammar, I've never heard of him. So I find the question unanswerable, sorry. The books may be used in other schools; I wouldn't know. However, my guess is that you should not trust any prohibitions you find in these books. English speakers do not follow those rules; indeed, they are unaware of them.

Comment: **Indicative (present)**: *I know that he will do the job well if he has the opportunity to arrive later.* 
**Indicative (past)**: *I knew that he would do the job well if he had the opportunity to arrive later.*
**Subjunctive (present)**: *I know that he would do the job well if he had the opportunity to arrive later.*
**Subjunctive (past)**: *I knew that he would have done the job well if he had had the opportunity to arrive later.*

Comment: @John Lawler I am grateful to you for attention to my questions, diffuse though. Maybe if I put it straight and simple you might answer my question. Is this sentence grammatically expedient: "Looking at him I knew that he would do the job well if he had the opportunity of arriving in a week"? (...he would do the job well if he had the opportunity of arriving in a week - a cluase of unreal condition, not real).

Comment: I really can't understand the _if_ clause; it's obviously made up by a non-native speaker so it might mean anything. What's wrong with _if he arrived in a week_? What does opportunity have to do with it? If he only had the opportunity to do it and didn't take the oppportunity, then he wouldn't do the job well. Maybe. The sentence doesn't really mean anything out of context; in some extremely particular context it might make sense. And you still haven't told us what country this is in and what languages you speak natively. This is important information.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat Thank you. So the Subjunctive (past) is to be used in past time contexts irrespective of whether the situation in conditional clause refers to the time before or after the author's time (i.e. "I knew that he would have done the job well if he had had the opportunity to arrive two weeks later/two weeks before")?

Comment: @John Lawler In fact this sentence is intended simply to show the grammar I am inquiring after. And after your remark I have grasped my mistake. It should be: "Looking at him at the railway station where I came to see him off I knew that he would be able to do the job well if they granted him the opportunity of turning back in a week" (but he returned in a month). Here both the main and the subourdinate clauses are those of unreal condition.

Comment: But I think that it is correct to use the Type 3 Conditional because the situation lies altogether in the demesne of the past.  I.e. "Looking at him at the railway station where I came to see him off I knew that he would have been able to do the job well if they had granted him the opportunity of turning back in a week"