# What type of Conditional grammar is this?

Tags: grammar, conditionals

In this sentence, if clause is present, but another clause comes with *would*.

I wonder what type of conditional is this.

> If you’re exhausted from the hustles and bustles of life, and you need to take a break, Thailand would be an ideal destination where you can recharge your batteries again.

Comment: I'd say it's a corruption of irrealis 'If you were exhausted from the hustles and bustles of life, and you needed to take a break, Thailand would be an ideal destination where you could recharge your batteries again.'

Comment: I don't think the "numbered conditional" here should be affected by whether it's expressed as *Thailand **would be** an ideal destination, Thailand **will be** an ideal destination,* or *Thailand **is** an ideal destination*. So far as I'm concerned, all those are perfectly valid, and *in context* they must mean exactly the same thing, so it would make no sense to claim that *that* verb choice makes any difference to which "conditional number" to assign. So basically, it's ***first conditional*** - which  expresses a future scenario that might occur.

Comment: The choice is between an **open** conditional and a **remote** conditional. The former is characteristically neutral as to whether the condition is or will be met, while the latter is a conditional where the condition is not fulfilled or presented as a relatively remote possibility. What type do you think your example is @Ali Hosseinli?

Comment: Define "type of conditional".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You actually know a standard numbering system for conditionals? Was it part of your education? Where? Is it online anywhere? More important, is it standard worldwide?

Comment: @JohnLawler: Certainly not! Periodically, you post comments like [*Numbered conditionals are peculiar to ESOL at individual schools and various textbooks. They aren't standard, and **most English speakers know nothing about them***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/563735/the-peculiarities-of-using-type2-type3-conditionals-with-regard-to-the-shifting#comment1394617_563735) here on ELU, and I *always* upvote them! I've never bothered to *remember* the most common 4 basic types, but the site I found before commenting said **Simple Present + Simple Future = Type 1**, so I extrapolated.

Comment: That **was**  my experience, but I figured maybe you might know different, being English.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, numbered conditionals are only used in ESL teaching, not scholarly grammar.